# Create child in XML within node by attribute name

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a XML file with following structure

```xml
<root>
    <system name="Windows-32bit">
    </system>
    <system name="Windows-64bit">
    </system>
    <system name="AIX-32bit">
    </system>
    <system name="Linux-32bit">
    </system>
</root>
```

and I want to insert a value in example to system node with name "Windiows-32bit" so this specific node looks like that

```xml
<system name="Windows-32bit">
    <file name="name1" md5="hash1" path="path1"/>
</system>
```

I know I can insert it with following method

```bsh
$wc_config = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$wc_config.Load("PATH")
$child = $wc_config.CreateElement("file")
$child.SetAttribute("name", "asdf")
$child.SetAttribute("md5", "asdasdfasdff")
$child.SetAttribute("path", "PATH")
$wc_config.DocumentElement.AppendChild($child)
```

But this adds created child within root. Not where I want it. How can I create child within specific XML node knowing its name and attribute value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$wc_config.DocumentElement` is the root node of the XML document, so obviously calling `AppendChild()` on that node would add the new node as a child of the root node. To add the new node as a child of a different node you need to call `AppendChild()` on *that* node.

```
$parent = $wc_config.SelectSingleNode("//system[@name='Windows-32bit']")
$parent.AppendChild($child)
```

The [XPath expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) `//system[@name='Windows-32bit']` selects a node `<system>` with an attribute `name` that has the value "Windows-32bit".

Comment: Thank you for explaining how to use xPath. However in your example there is a mistake - xPath should be `//root/system[@name='Windows-32bit']`. Because you didn't specify any steps to get "inside" root. That is why when I get `parent` directly after loading `$wc_config` path is still outside of root

Comment: @Uliysess There is no mistake. `//` means "anywhere below the document root". You could make the expression more specific (`/root/system`, meaning "a node `<system>` below a node `<root>` in the document root"), but that is not required unless you have another matching node earlier in the document.